# This is taking too long!

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

Move two lines to make the equation true.

[image]

As always, no inequality symbol (≠), adding, and subtracting lines. Move the lines only.

Hint 1:

> To find the answer, you only have to affect one side.

Hint 2:

> Do not rotate lines as well.

Comment: This is honestly terrible unless there's an actual answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move two vertical lines from 7 to the left, to get:

> [image]

Explanation:

> Italy calling country code is +39. Many sites and documents do not explicitly use "+" sign.

Comment: So + sign is not needed?

Answer (score 15):

> Here's a more conventional answer: 
> [image]

Comment: Didn't think of that, pretty clever !

Comment: @Auribouros Thanks. Isn't quite in keeping with the hint, but still.

Comment: This is supposed to mean "raised to the power of zero"?

Comment: @justhalf Yup. :)

Comment: Shocked that this wasn't it...

Comment: Except, there are 3 problems with this:  (1) 3^0 =1,  (2) hint2 said no rotation, and (3) it appears that you've added a new matchstick, whereas the instructions said move only.

Comment: Your points are invalid: (1) 1^0 also = 1, so it's valid (2) If a hint precludes an otherwise valid solution it should be in the puzzle itself, not posted later (3) If you count properly, exactly two matchsticks have been moved (red matchsticks are moved to green positions)

Answer (score 10):

Using Lateral Thinking you can rotate the equation 180 degrees and move 2 sticks to get

> Sb = LI   or

> [image]

Reason is

> Sb is Antimony in the Periodic Table with atomic number 51 and LI is 51 in Roman Numeral!

Answer (score 6):

> 17 < 39
>  (17 is less than 39)
>
>  [image]

Comment: Welcome to the puzzling stackexchange. Please make sure to use spoiler tags next time (by prepending your answer with `>! `). I went ahead and edited your post to do so (and I also added a picture). Nice answer though, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), you can

> flip the image 180 degrees, and move the sticks from the 1 to get the letter "b", which is phonetically equivalent to "be".
>  [image: The equation 17 = 39 in matchsticks, flipped upside down. The sticks from the 1 in 17 have been moved to turn the upside-down 7 into the letter b. The upside-down 39 reads as the letters b and e.]

Answer (score 3):

In line with the hint and the lateral thinking tag.

> [image: 17] 
>  17=17, where the right hand side are the

I am not entirely convinced with myself because the seven looks clunky.

Answer (score 1):

> The equation is already true, if the left side is base32, and the right side is base10.

Answer (score 1):

> If the left side is Celsius, and the right side is Fahrenheit, then with 3 non-rotation moves on the right side only, you can get 17=63

Notes:

> Since modifications should be limited to one side of the equation, and you can't rotate, we can infer that the 17 will not change (because you must use all 4 verticals, only "8" has 4 verticals, but there aren't enough horizontals).
>
>  So if we assume the 17 is constant, there must be some regime where 17 matches some other number. (I'm discounting base32 and base10 for this answer, since 2 moves are required.)
>
>  17C equals 62.6F, which if we round up, then 63 can be achieved with 3 non-rotating moves.

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

Because

> Both sides follow different number systems, LHS is in hex and RHS is in decimal and 17 in hex is 23 in decimal

Comment: 17 in base 32 equals 39 in decimal already.

Comment: Can be said that base 32 is "too long" (long=32 bits)

Answer (score 0):

My thinking was to move two sticks from the right to the left to get something like this

> [image]

indicating that

> The ["crossed seven"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numeral_variations#Other_variations) is to be interpreted in the same way as a regular seven.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

> Using different numbering systems

> [image: Move two sticks to create LI = 33, or, Roman Numeral 51 = Hexadecimal 51]

Answer (score 0):

I'll give my shot:

> [image: 11 = 34x]

A mathematically sound equation... just likely not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I don't understand?